# mysql workbench models cannot save

Tags: mysql, models, workbench

I used MySQL workbench version 6.2.3, and tried to create a new model, after i clicked "save model to current file", it's appear an error and shutdown my workbench. I've try checking for update, and it's the newest version, so I think maybe is not the old version problem.

Comment: I can't see any error in my log file, because workbench shutdown right after i click the save botton.

Comment: Maybe I know the problem, it's solved when i don't save it into Dropbox folder, but i still don't know why?